# Filtering a list of objects, looking for a single positive result

Tags: scala, stream

The problem: Find a series of objects and for each object check a condition however we only need to find this condition once for the method isWhat to return it's value.

```
def isWhat: Boolean = SomeGenerator.findAll().filter(_.someCondition).size > 0
```

The above code will call someCondition on each and every object even if one is already found to have the required condition.

There are much better ways to write this overall however let's assume we do not have access to modify the someCondition code -- if that were the case how could this be written at the level above to not make any needless calls?

Stream comes to mind...

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not going to drag hundreds of lines of code and a massive data store into the example :) It illustrates the problem that is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exists` method is lazy on all of the standard library collections (not just `Stream`). For example:

```
case class Foo(i: Int) {
  def check(): Boolean = {
    printnln(s"Checking $this")
    i > 0
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> List(Foo(-10), Foo(-50), Foo(1), Foo(-3)).exists(_.check())
Checking Foo(-10)
Checking Foo(-50)
Checking Foo(1)
res2: Boolean = true
```

Which shows that we stop checking once we've found an element that passes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called [`exists(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): Boolean`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) defined on Scala's [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) which will lazily evaluate your predicate, and return with `true` as soon as it finds an element, or with `false` if there is no element fulfilling your condition

```
def isWhat: Boolean = SomeGenerator.findAll().exists(_.someCondition)
```

Comment: See - this is why it's good to ask questions! Awesome answer and works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Face Palm....

```
def isWhat: Boolean = SomeGenerator.findAll().toStream.filter(_.someCondition).size > 0
```

Is it really that easy?

Will this do what we expect?

Comment: `filter` returns a stream here, which isn't something you can compare with an integer. Can you include more of your code?

Comment: using a stream here won't really make your program any faster

Comment: Not trying to make the code run faster @kosii - trying not to run code at all :)